# How can I change a:active link color Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My a href Link active color doesn't work on my page.

Can you give me a hint/guide how can i change the active a:link color for the following code block.?

I did change the twitter Bootstrap as like below.. but that color is not showed when the link is clicked and the menu is collapsed.

```
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
  color: #E57200 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="panel-title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-1" href="#panel-element-15">About us</a>
  </div>
  <div id="panel-element-15" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>
       About us Content will come here....
      </p>
```

Comment: How can you tell it isn't working? You say you are testing it by clicking it, so you must be triggering `:hover` at the same time and `:hover` has the same styles as `:active`. It sounds like you misunderstand what `:active` means.

Comment: Sorry first for my unclear questions here. I would like to have the a:active color 

color: #E57200
When the menu is "collapsed". 

Currently my active link color is still default color: #428bca.

regards,
Thomas

Comment: That doesn't make things any clearer, or address my comment at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've created [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/65/)

Looks like your styles work fine

```
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the value like you've already done, or you can modify `variables.less` on line ~37 where there's a variable called `@link-hover-color`. If you go with this option you'll need to re-compile `bootstrap.less`, the benefit of doing this is that you'll have control over all the Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You must modify the `@link-hover-color` variable.

I suggest that you use their customize tool which can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#scaffolding).

You can customize all bootstrap components and create a custom build.

You should use their tool even for that one link since they will also take care of the build and you will not need a local LESS compiler.